Why is the triangular inequality not applicable in this case?

In $Oxyz$ space, consider three points $A(-1;0;0), B(0;-1; 0), C(0;0;1)$ and the plane $(P): 2x - 2y + z + 7 = 0.$ Consider $M \in (P).$ What is the smallest value of $S = |\vec{MC} + \vec{MB} - \vec{MA}| + |\vec{MB}|$?

Here's the outline of my solution:
Let $I$ be the point such that $\vec{IC} + \vec{IB} - \vec{IA} = \vec{0} \implies I(1; -1; 1)$
We have $S= |\vec{MC} + \vec{MB} - \vec{MA}| + |\vec{MB}| = |\vec{MI} + (\vec{IC} + \vec{IB} - \vec{IA})| + |\vec{MB}| = |\vec{MI}| + |\vec{MB}| = MI + MB$
Since $(I, (P)) = 2 + 2 + 1 + 7 = 12 >  (B, (P)) = 0 + 2 + 0 + 7 = 7 > 0,$ $I$ and $B$ are on the same side with respect to $(P).$
Let $B'$ be the reflection of $B$ in $(P)$. Then $MI + MB = MI + MB',$ so $(MI + MB)$ assumes the smallest value when $I$ is the intersection of $(P)$ and line $IB'.$ From there, we could find $\min\{S\} = IB'.$

The last paragraph, however, wasn't my first idea. When I got to $S = |\vec{MI}| + |\vec{MB}|,$ I first thought of the triangular inequality: $S = |\vec{MI}| + |\vec{MB}| \geq |\vec{MI} + \vec{MB}|.$ The equality occurs when $\vec{MI}$ and $\vec{MB}$ point to the same direction, and since $M \in (P),$ it follows that $M$ is the intersection of $IB$ and $(P).$ At this point, it dawned on me that there was some issue with this reasoning, as clearly a smaller value of $MI + MB$ could be achieved when $M$ is somewhere in the image of $IB$ on $(P).$ Though I was able to pivot from this line of reasoning, I couldn't seem to find what went wrong with it even in hindsight. I've also always felt that I don't have a good understanding of the triangular inequality, so hopefully this will clarify it. Please advise!
Thank you!


Your reasoning would work if $|\vec{MI}+\vec{MB}|$ were a fixed quantity, but it depends on the position of $M$.
